# Batch file still prints error messages after using @echo off and >nul

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I wrote a batch file to close all programs before the computer attempts to shut down, using the `taskkill` function to end specific programs. I used `@echo off` at the start, and wrote `>null` at the end of my taskkill function, but I still got a command prompt window detailing errors where taskkill did not find a program that was told to be closed. I am running Windows 10, if that helps.

Here are the two lines of code that are misbehaving:

```
@echo off 
taskkill -f -t -im chrome.exe -im skype.exe -im WINWORD.exe >nul
```

And here is the full batch file if you want to see it:

```
REM Closes all programs, THEN turns off computer
@echo off 
::  If you want to make a command prompt window appear, change this to “@echo on”
taskkill -f -t -im chrome.exe -im skype.exe -im WINWORD.exe >nul
::  Add all your program names here and an “/im” before them. Also if you want them to give you prompts before 
::  shutting down, delete the "-f". Delete the ">nul"s if you want error messages
timeout 4 >nul
::  This will make the computer wait for between 3 and 4 seconds. This is designed for slower computers,
::  you can make the time delay less if you want
shutdown.exe -p -f >nul
::  This shuts down computer. -p makes it not have a time delay or display a message, -f quits programs just in case
exit 
::  Exits in case it prevents computer from shutting down
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `>nul` in my title, not ">null"

Answer (score 1):

StdOut and StdError are different. You have only redirected StdOut.

To redirect StdError to wherever StdOut is going, put somewhere on the line

```
2>&1
```

Cmd actually changes `>` to `1>` (you'll see this in your batch if you remove `echo off`).

To redirect StdError to somewhere different

```
2> filename.txt

0=keyboard
1=screen for normal output
2=screen for error
3-9=whatever other files Cmd has open
```

Comment: You should note that redirecting ther stdErr to stdOut should happen after stdOut is changed to redirect to nul, [as this fails otherwise](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3734)

Answer (score 1):

The >nul discards output sent to stdout, or file descriptor 1. Most commands send error messages to a separate channel, stderr (2). You can redirect stderr to nul using `2> nul`. (Make sure there is no space between the `2` and the `>`; otherwise, the `2` will be taken as a parameter to the command.) To discard both stderr and stdout at the same time it is usual to do this:

```
taskkill ... >nul 2>&1
```

which means redirect stdout to nul and also treat stderr the same way as stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that :

```
@echo off
set process=mshta.exe,chrome.exe,calc.exe,skype.exe,iexplore.exe
For %%a in (%process%) Do Call :KillMyProcess %%a

:KillMyProcess
Taskkill /IM "%1" /F >nul 2>&1
```